# How to convert from lat,lng to tile coordinates?

Tags: carto

Given a pair of lat/long coordinates (and a screen size if needed), we need to establish the Z/X/Y coordinates for the map tiles which will be requested when we tell our map `fitBounds(coordinatePair);`.

**Background**

We're trying to load test our map application. Our test partner uses NeoLoad, which I don't understand too well, but I think it stands in place of the page on the browser.  It seems to fire requests based on the recording, and allows us to parameterise them to simulate real usage - rather than repeatedly doing exactly the same thing (and getting the same piece of land in the resulting map).

We're having trouble parameterising the tile requests, which is unfortunate, because that's the main purpose of the load test.

Our map allows users to enter a text search string to help them find a piece of land.  Then we figure out the `coordinatePair` and show it on the map.  But while coordinatePair is in degrees, the resulting requests to the map server use the Z/X/Y coordinate system.

So we can't get our load tests to get map tiles corresponding to the right piece of land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at CARTO

Take a look at the `getVisibleTiles` function of this [minimal XYZ viewer](https://gist.github.com/jsanz/e8549c7bffd442235a942695ffdaf77d) where given a pair of coordinates, a zoom level and screen size it will return the tileset.

Mind also that load testing a CARTO SaaS service is against the terms of service so if detected and flagged as affecting the platform your account may be disabled.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I'm still not clear.  Which of `https://our-user-name.carto.com` and `https://our-on-premises-carto-service.com` fall under the CARTO SaaS load testing restriction you mention? Thanks

Comment: `https://our-user-name.carto.com` sure, anything outside CARTO SaaS can't be under any restriction from our side, it is totally up to you to load test your own hardware. Hope this clarifies.